# Return List<String> using Spring jdbc from Oracle stored procedure having custom object

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have created a custom table in Oracle as below and my stored procedure returning the list when test independently using test data.

```
   create or replace TYPE  NAMELIST AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
```

But when I am trying to call this stored procedure using Java spring, I am not able to return the `List<String>`.

```
 declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter('l_out', OracleTypes.ARRAY, 'NAMELIST',
                new SqlReturnArray()));
```

How can we return the custom list from Oracle in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple Java method of doing this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;

public class TestDatabaseArray
{
  public static void main( final String[] args )
  {
    try{
      Class.forName( "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" );

      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
          "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
          "username",
          "password"
        );

      OracleCallableStatement st
        =(OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall("{ call get_names( :out_array ) }");

      st.registerOutParameter( 1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY, "NAMELIST" );

      st.execute();

      String[] names = (String[]) st.getARRAY( 1 ).getArray();

      for ( final String name : names )
        System.out.println( name );
    }
    catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex )
    {
      System.out.println( ex.getMessage() );
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```