# How to pass values to IN operator dynamically?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to create a procedure which accepts an array list for IN operator.

For eg:

```
Create or Replace Procedure Test (a Arraylist)
{
Select * from table1 where col1 IN (Arraylist)
}
```

If the procedure is called using two parameters then the query should be

```
Select * from table1 where col1 IN (val1,val2)
```

If the procedure is called using one parameter then the query should be

```
Select * from table1 where col1 IN (val1)
```

Comment: Do you want to pass in an array (collection) of values; or just overload the procedure with different argument lists?

Comment: in an array (collection) of values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a collection type:

```
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/
```

Then you can pass it to a procedure and use the `MEMBER OF` operator (rather than the `IN` operator):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test (
  in_list     IN  stringlist,
  out_results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN out_results FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   your_table
  WHERE  your_column MEMBER OF in_list;
END;
/
```

If you are connecting from an external language then you can quite easily pass an array to the procedure ([Java example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264)) or you can create the list in PL/SQL or from a [delimited list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381747/1509264).

Comment: how is this procedure called from java ?

Comment: @user2190186 See the linked example in my answer. Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160300/how-to-pass-list-from-java-to-oracle-procedure/37161584#37161584) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42201985/1509264).