# Java passing values into IN in sql WHERE clause

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, where-in

I have a sql query like

```
(sqlQuery)
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE to_char(id) in (?)
```

Then in my prepared statement

```
preparedStatement ps = new preparedStatemend(sqlQuery)
ps.setString(1,param);
```

where my param is a string chain looking like `param = '12','34', '444'`

Now, I thought that when I execute it then everything will be ok, but it's not and I get and error like ORA 01460 uninmplemented or unreasonable conversion.

So, how can I pass my parameter consists of a few valuse into the IN clause in sql query?

Comment: Simple pass List<String> into the IN clause i.e. convert params into List<String> rather than a single String with commas.

Comment: you should pass a `Set<String>`

Comment: This is more of an SQL question than a Java question. But the issue is that you need as many question marks `?` as you have parameters. So you'll need to create your `PreparedStatement` for each time you use it.

Comment: *where my param is a string chain looking like `param = '12','34', '444'`* I trust you are checking for things like SQL Injection when doing things like that?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you will get better performance with `where id in (?)` than what you have now.

Comment: How many IDs are you passing to the string? The IN clause can't exceed 4000 characters (SQL limit).

Comment: Actually, since this is oracle, the limiting factor is 1000 list items, max.

Comment: @DanBracuk Use an Oracle collection: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id MEMBER OF ?` and then [pass in a collection as the bind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43179008/1509264) which can [have more than 1000 items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to specify a `?` for each possible values of the IN clause.

For example if you have 4 options possible in the `IN` clause, this :

```
to_char(id) in (?)
```

should so be :

```
to_char(id) in (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And  you should also set each parameter by incrementing successively the index of the param to set :

So this :

```
ps.setString(1,param);
```

should be :

```
int index = 1;
for( String s : inValues ) {
   ps.setString(index++, s); 
}
```

Comment: `to_char(id) in ('?', '?', '?', '?') ` Surely without the single quotes?

Comment: Normally it's without quotes at all (single or double), other than the quotes that surround the entire query.

Comment: @Joe C In terms of SQL sure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know that there is limit for the data can be in the `IN` clause. So if you have a large number of comma separated values to pass as the parameter (bind variable) of the `IN` clause you should manage something else.

Now if you have a limited number of ids (for example less than 500 or so, depends on the size of ids which totally can not be more than 4000 characters) you can use the `regexp_substr` along with `connect by` to tokenize the comma separated values of your single parameter `?` in the where clause: `to_char(id) in (?)` :

```
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(? ,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(? , '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

when you pass the string `"'12','34', '444'"` as the parameter, it would tokenize them as rows:

> '12'
>
> '34'
>
> '444'

So theoretically you can change your query in this way:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE to_char(id) in 
 (
       SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(? ,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM dual
      CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(? , '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
 )
```

**But** in this way if the size of the `table1` is big the performance would be so bad because of the conversion of the `id` for every record.

It's better to convert your limited number of parameters of the `IN` clause to enhance the performance:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE id in 
 (
       SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(? ,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM dual
      CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(? , '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
 )
```

and in your java code you should pass the string `"12,34, 444"` as the parameter (without single single quotes around each id).

You should know that this solution is not optimized for a large number of ids. However, it makes the number of parameters of the `IN` clause dynamic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but my table is pretty big- milions of records

Comment: The big size of the table is not a problem here. The performance can be bad if the number of comma separated ids grows too big. In every situation using IN clause can harm the performance.